# Как принять текущую дату с JS на C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

Всем привет.
Отправляю с JS на бекенд дату в UTC в таком виде : Tue, 09 Aug 2022 07:03:41 GMT

Как эту дату для типа DataTime обработать на стороне бекенда?
И вернуть время с учетом +3 (Московское время)

На данный момент как бы я не передавал дату мне возращается : 0001-01-01T00:00:00

Comment: Покажите код пожалуйста

Comment: А зачем эти извращения вместо простого числа unixtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JavaScript**

Берете дату

```js
const date = new Date();
console.log(date);
```

Получаете

```
Tue Aug 09 2022 11:57:50 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)
```

Далее делаете

```js
const timeStamp = date.getTime();
console.log(timeStamp);
```

То есть вызываете функцию `.getTime()` для для объекта типа `Date`.

Получаете

```
1660035470640
```

Это UNIX таймштамп в миллисекундах. Отправляете его на бэк числом.

**C#**

Принимаете как `long`

```cs
long timeStamp = 1660035470640;
DateTime date = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(timeStamp).DateTime.ToLocalTime();
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

Получаете вывод, для меня это UTC+3

```
09.08.2022 11:57:50
```

Без `.ToLocalTime()` получится UTC `8:57:50`

Или если будет угодно в универсальном формате

```cs
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("s"));
```

```
2022-08-09T11:57:50
```

Comment: а можно и по быдлокодерски
str = date.getFullYear()+"-"+(date.getMonth()+1)+"-"+date.getDay()+"T"+date.getHours()+":"+date.getMinutes()+":"+date.getSeconds();
Только надо нули перед месяцами/днями/часами/минутами ставить, если длина меньше 2. Вспомнил еще вариант - date.toJSON()

Comment: @Ajmda так тоже пробовал ))
Я перепробовал кучу подходов в итоге пришел к тому что распихал везде где только можно точки останова и отловил ошибку "InvalidCastException: Cannot write DateTime with Kind=Unspecified to PostgreSQL type 'timestamp with time zone', only UTC is supported. Note that it's not possible to mix DateTimes with different Kinds in an array/range. See the Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior AppContext switch to enable legacy behavior." .... Вот почему у меня проблемы с добавленгием даты. Правда пока решение ошибки не нашел

Comment: @VadimTregubenko, это ошибка бэка. Глянь здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69961449/net6-and-datetime-problem-cannot-write-datetime-with-kind-utc-to-postgresql-ty

Comment: @Ajmda такой подход помог :) DateTime.SpecifyKind(date, DateTimeKind.Utc);
Спасибо